# how to delete a component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to delete it.But it won't be deleted.
If you click the delete text in the modal, it should be deleted, but it doesn't work.What should I do to delete it?
There's an error saying that onRemove is not a function.Please help me.

I want to delete it.But it won't be deleted.
If you click the delete text in the modal, it should be deleted, but it doesn't work.What should I do to delete it?
There's an error saying that onRemove is not a function.Please help me.

```
export default function Modal({ onRemove, id }) {
  return (
    <OptionModalWrap>
      <ModalWrapper>
        <TitleWrap>Edit</TitleWrap>
        <TitleWrap>Duplicate</TitleWrap>
        <DeleteText onClick={() => onRemove(id)}>Delete</DeleteText>
      </ModalWrapper>
    </OptionModalWrap>
  );
}
```

```
export default function GroupList({ title, onRemove }) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const optionModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <AdGroups>
      <Header>
        <Container>
          <ActiveWrap>
            <ActiveIcon src={Active} />
            <SubTitle>Active</SubTitle>
          </ActiveWrap>
          <Alaram>
            <Bell src={bell} />
            <Text className="alarmCount">10</Text>
          </Alaram>
        </Container>
        <EtcIconWrap>
          <EtcIcon src={plus} onClick={optionModal} />
          {showModal && (
            <OptionModal showModal={showModal} onRemove={onRemove} />
          )}
        </EtcIconWrap>
      </Header>
      <GroupTitle>{title}</GroupTitle>
    </AdGroups>
  );
}
```

```
export default function GroupPage() {
  const [Groupdata, setGroupData] = useState([]);

  const onRemove = item => {
    setGroupData(Groupdata.filter(item => item.id !== item));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./data/AdsGroup/AdsGroupList.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setGroupData(res));
  }, []);

  return (
    <GroupPages>
      {Groupdata.map(item => {
        return (
          <GroupList key={item.id} title={item.title} onRemove={onRemove} />
        );
      })}
    </GroupPages>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is `Modal` the same as `OptionModal`? Why aren't you passing the `id` as a prop?

Comment: The id must match to be deleted.So I was passing the ID as a prop.

Comment: `<OptionModal showModal={showModal} onRemove={onRemove} />` id is not passed

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the `id` in `GroupList` and then also to the `OptionModal` component.

So here is the revised code:

**Group Page Component:**

Passing the `id` to `GroupList Component`

```
const onRemove = id => {
    setGroupData(Groupdata.filter(item => item.id !== id)); // you were item.id !== item which was wrong
  };

<GroupList key={item.id} title={item.title} id={item.id} onRemove={onRemove} /> // passing the id
```

**Group List Component:**

Added `id` in the props and passed that to `Modal Component`. Also calling `optionModal` function to close the Modal after it deleted

```
export default function GroupList({ id, title, onRemove }) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const optionModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <AdGroups>
      <Header>
        <Container>
          <ActiveWrap>
            <ActiveIcon src={Active} />
            <SubTitle>Active</SubTitle>
          </ActiveWrap>
          <Alaram>
            <Bell src={bell} />
            <Text className="alarmCount">10</Text>
          </Alaram>
        </Container>
        <EtcIconWrap>
          <EtcIcon src={plus} onClick={optionModal} />
          {showModal && (
            <OptionModal id={id} showModal={showModal} onRemove={onRemove;optionModal} />
          )}
        </EtcIconWrap>
      </Header>
      <GroupTitle>{title}</GroupTitle>
    </AdGroups>
  );
}
```

**Modal Component:** No change in this component

```
export default function Modal({ onRemove, id }) {
  return (
    <OptionModalWrap>
      <ModalWrapper>
        <TitleWrap>Edit</TitleWrap>
        <TitleWrap>Duplicate</TitleWrap>
        <DeleteText onClick={() => onRemove(id)}>Delete</DeleteText>
      </ModalWrapper>
    </OptionModalWrap>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is Error.
The part where the error occurs...  {showModal && (
            <OptionModal id={id} showModal={showModal} onRemove={onRemove;optionModal} />
          )}

Comment: I corrected the error, but it is not deleted.

Comment: Can you put a console on onRemove function to check whether the control is coming there or not? Also, print the item inside onRemove to check whether you are getting the corrected id?

Comment: It doesn't work.So instead of onRemove in the GroupPage, I made a handleDelete. 

const handleDelete = id => {
setGroupData(Groupdata.filter(item => item.id !== id));
};


So it's deleted.

Comment: @99cone Oh yes, so you got the issue or not? in onRemove you were comparing like `item.id !== item` that's wrong. It should be item.id !== id. See I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't your IDE complaint about this piece of code? both of the onRemove & filter functions' props are called `item`, it shouldn't be.

```
  const onRemove = itemId => {
    setGroupData(Groupdata.filter(item => item.id !== itemId));
  };
```